# Why httpclient use AESCipher

Tags: java, httpclient

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use this httpasyncclient, it performs different in jdk1.7 and jdk1.8. The first picture is 1.8. why 1.8 use AESCiper?
[image]

In 1.7[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the cypher suite used differ from different version of TLS. And the suported version of TLS differ from the different JDK version ([including minor one for java 1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html))